# Extract data from Json Response in Angular Component

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

basically i have angular component which is getting response from WEBApi as below

```
export class FetchDataComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _httpService: Http) { }

    City: string[] = [];


    ngOnInit() {

        // city and country

        this._httpService.get('/api/City').subscribe(values => {

            this.City = values.json() as string[];

        });


    }
}
```

The response I get here is ["Waterloo","Canada"]

how do I extract the city Waterloo from the response above? according to requirement, I need to do it here.

i am trying to store waterloo in separate variable and Canada in separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is Array of Strings:

```
City: string[] = [];
var1: string;
var2: string;
ngOnInit() {    
    this._httpService.get('/api/City').subscribe(values => {
        this.City = values.json() as string[];
        this.var1 = this.City[0];
        this.var2 = this.City[1];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question right. If you wanted to get the "Waterloo" from your `City` object, you can just use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
var item = this.City.find(x => x == 'Waterloo');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
City: string[] = [];
ngOnInit() {    
    this._httpService.get('/api/City').subscribe(values => {
        this.City = values.json() as string[];
        var city = this.City.find(x => x === 'Waterloo'(please input city you want to get));
    });
}
```